# Back button to previous page and breadcrumbs

Tags: buttons, paths, breadcrumb

I must add back button only on one page and only when I get to this page from one specific.

If I on B Page and go to A Page -> display button od A Page but if I on C Page and go to A Page - button should be hidden on A Page.

How can I do that?

Second question. How can I make breadcrumbs for one specific page? I have some section on page and I need path to follow them. User should can choose at any time from this list interesting section.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

For the button behavior,

If it's a one-off use case, you could add custom php conditional to check the referring url  $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] and current page/post ID or url.  Then, either add a class to the button's containing div wrapper in the template for hiding via css or directly output/include the button html in the template file itself.

If it applies for various cases, I'd recommend  creating an array of 2-d arrays (referrer url or post id, target url or post id).  Then use (setting/checking) a session cookie to  loop through the array to see if any conditions are satisfied and in turn, show or hide button

Comment: Thx, I try it :)